# Python - Módulo: Tkinter - manipulação de janelas

Tags: python, tkinter

como todo bom e novo programador, no inicio surge muitas ideias e, uma delas foi a seguinte: como eu faço para manipular a janelas? como assim?

- retirar os cantos arrendondados quando executado no Windows 7.
- mudar a cor (background) onde fica o nome, o ícone e os botões de minimizar, máximinizar e fechar.

Comment: Por favor, se isso não for possível avisem-me.

Answer (score 1):

Para tirar as bordas/decoração de uma janela no `TkInter` use o método:

```
.overrideredirect(True)
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button

class Exemplo:
    def __init__(self, aplicacao):

        # Remove as bordas/decoração
        aplicacao.overrideredirect(True)

        #Cor de fundo como no exemplo da outra resposta
        root["bg"] = "gray"

        self.label = Label(aplicacao, text="Primeira janela")
        self.label.pack()

        self.greet_button = Button(aplicacao, text="Chamar função", command=self.minhafuncao)
        self.greet_button.pack()

        self.close_button = Button(aplicacao, text="Fechar", command=aplicacao.quit)
        self.close_button.pack()

    def minhafuncao(self):
        print("Testando!")

root = Tk()
minhajanela = Exemplo(root)
root.mainloop()
```

> **Nota:** O `.overrideredirect(True)` também pode se aplicado em uma janela/widget especifica.

Então após aplicar o `overrideredirect` você pode criar o seu próprio maximizar, minimizar ou "decoração" (bordas) próprias.

Answer (score 0):

Mudar o título da janela:

`janela.title("Janela Principal")`

Mudar o fundo dentro da janela:

`janela["bg"] = "green"`

Agora fazer as alterações de mudança de cor na Barra de Títulos da Aplicação e arredondamento dos cantos não sei te informar.

Comment: como mudar a cor de fundo do title ?